# Why does multi-location Azure make adding templates so slow?

Tags: azure, publishing

We are deploying a multi-location Sitecore deployment into Azure. The CMS and one CD runs out of Europe. For front end performance reasons we are also hosting a CD over in Australia - a CDN is not a viable option for the traffic profile we have.

The speed of publishing is a known issue however has been accepted by the client and the plan is to move to using the publishing service.

However an odd issue we have is when you add a template via the UI (or API) it takes a LONG TIME.

Why might this be? I'd have thought all the operations that are needed would be run against master/core within Europe. As soon as we remove the `<database>` node for Australia the problem goes away.

Is there anything we could disable within Sitecore to prevent the speed issues we are seeing?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that automatic publishing was the culprit here. The setting `<setting name="Publishing.AutoScheduleSmartPublish" value="true" />` was causing any new template to get push to each remote target - in the case of Australia this was adding a long time to each operation!

Read a bit more here: https://alenpelin.com/2017/08/17/auto-schedule-smart-publish/